# Arduino MEGA2560 Standalone

Tags: atmega2560

I had an Arduino UNO (ATmega168) standalone working, but I need more pins, and I decided to use the ATmega2560, I was searching for some schematics, and none of them shown an ATmega2560 standalone, only the full Arduino, with the FTDI, power transformers... etc integrated. So taking parts from those designs, I made this, but I don't know if it's enough or I need Something more:
[image]

Note: VCC2 is connected to 5V.

Comment: Looks like R1 has both sides connected to GND.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/MCUdude/MegaCore#minimal-setup

Comment: See http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2521-AVR-Hardware-Design-Considerations_ApplicationNote_AVR042.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You need more decoupling capacitors - one per VCC and AVCC pin, plus a larger (10µF) for the whole chip.

You need a pullup resistor (and maybe button) on RESET.

Comment: In theory (page 58 and 355 of the datasheet) the reset line has already a 30-60 kOhm pull-up resistor. 

Yes, it might not be enough in very noisy/humid/dirty environments (as I found sometimes). I also always put a 10kOhm: it does not harm.

Comment: So it does. I'm used to MCUs with no internal pullup, but yes, it's good to add a proper external one anyway since that is quite a high value for a pullup.

Comment: Especially if you plan to use an external DTR+100nF based reset circuit for programming - the lower pullup value will recharge the capacitor faster.

Comment: Here in the Arduino forum: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=152319.msg1143618#msg1143618 they say that just changing the processor, will be enough to work, basing on this: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard.

Answer (score 1):

1. check the datasheet;
2. I would put a pull-up on the reset pin, plus a small capacitor;
3. crystal + capacitors as optional;
4. AVCC to VCC with filtering, if you need good analog performance;
5. separate Vbat domain, if it has one.

...